# Accessing Image from App_data folder

Tags: asp.net

I want to store some images in app_data folder, I know its a secure folder
but I don't know how I can access this Image file from HTML (no Image appears)

are there any suggestion, or how I can store my image in a secure place that not accessible from external user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you started.

```
namespace Moo.Core.Handlers
{
    public class Thumbnail : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            String FileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath).Replace(".th", "");
            String AssetName = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, "UserData/Images/" + FileName));

            if (File.Exists(AssetName))
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = ImageManipulation.TypeOf(AssetName).MimeType;
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(AssetName));
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a more complete answer, can you also add any configuration for the handler (if necessary) and how one would reference an image in HTML using this handler?

Comment: I will do when I'm back at a pc.

Answer (score 1):

The [App_Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) folder is designed to be hold databases, XML files and other forms of data storage. There's no need to store your images there. Instead, create a folder elsewhere and use your web server to disable directory browsing on that folder. In the end, if the user can see the image, they can access it one way or the other but disabling directory browser means they can't just traverse the folders like you can in Windows Explorer, for example.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to control access to the images, you can store files in your data base and get them as a binary image to the users you want. Example:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

You can learn more about it [here](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/).