# Returning JSON with ASP.NET and $.getJSON

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, getjson

I have a page that connects to the Northwind database to get a list of categories...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnnString"].ConnectionString);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryName", cnn);
        using (cnn)
        {
            cnn.Open();
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

                using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                    jw.WriteStartArray();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        jw.WriteStartObject();
                        jw.WritePropertyName("CategoryID");
                        jw.WriteValue(dr.GetInt32(0));
                        jw.WritePropertyName("CategoryName");
                        jw.WriteValue(dr.GetString(1));
                        jw.WriteEndObject();
                    }
                    jw.WriteEndArray();
                    jw.Flush();
                    Response.Write(sb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works just as expected. In my calling page I have a dropdownlist and I'm trying to use jQuery to populate it. Maybe I'm doing this wrong. I'm assuming that it takes the entire text from the .aspx file which includes the  and  strings and causes it to be invalid? If so, what is the correct way to do this, or what is it that I am doing wrong?

```
$.getJSON('GetCategories.aspx', function (data) {
        alert('success!');
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            $('#ddlCategories').append('<option></option>').val(key).html(val);
        });
    });
```

The alert never happens so it craps out getting the file. The file name is correct as Chrome Inspector gives me no console errors.

Comment: Can you post your solution and mark it as the answer?

Comment: This was a while ago, I will look for it later and see what it was and post it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into HttpHandlers, as they have much lower overhead and can be restricted to just the output you want.

I use a HttpHandler as an example in another answer here [Accessing Image from App_data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702071/accessing-image-from-app-data-folder/8702326#8702326)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll look into it at another time, but just trying to learn how what I've got goin here first. So from this example, say I have a div on my GetCategories.aspx page the I write the JSON into... with $.getJSON() can I grab a particular element from the GetCategories.aspx page?

Comment: I got this to work I'm good now, thanks for your help though.